# output PDF using DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, openxml-sdk

is there a way to output PDF using DocumentFormat.OpenXml?

Answer (score 1):

No

(sorry)

Aspose Words for .Net might do the trick for you, though.

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

Also, http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/ seems like a comprehensive tool, but I have not used it.

Answer (score 0):

Try PDFsharp for export to PDF: its open source and works

[**http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/**](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)